# how to return animation to it's original size and position on a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am relatively new to all this so if you see anything I am doing wrong, or anyways to simplify any code please do not hesitate to say.

I have the following code to enlarge the div element:

```
var profilePostsClick = function () {
    $('.largeBox, .smallBox, .longBox').click(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '100%',
            height: '40%'
        }, 200);
        $('.closePost', this).removeClass('closePostHide');
    });
};
$(document).ready(profilePostsClick);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jvkhmpbt/

I am wanting to close each div when the cross is clicked, returning it to it's original size and positioning (with height: auto if feasible).

Aslo is there a way to make it so each div opens above the smaller ones? (like the top left div does, i am aware this is because of it's positioning)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the animation properties/values in an cache-object and restore them after your animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/jvkhmpbt/4/

```
var animationResetCache = [];

var saveValues = function (node) {
    animationResetCache.push({
        node: node,
        width: node.css('width'),
        height: node.css('height')
    });
};

var restoreValues = function (node) {
    for (var i = 0; i < animationResetCache.length; ++i) {
        var item = animationResetCache[i];
        if (item.node.is(node)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
};


var profilePostsClick = function () {
    $('.largeBox, .smallBox, .longBox').click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.hasClass('open')) return;

        saveValues($this);

        $this.addClass('open').animate({
            width: '100%',
            height: '40%'
        }, 200);

        $this.find('.closePost').removeClass('closePostHide');
    });


    $('.closePost').click(function () {
        var $parent = $(this).parent('.largeBox, .smallBox, .longBox');

        if ($parent.hasClass('open')) {
            var cachedValues = restoreValues($parent);

            $parent.animate({
                width: cachedValues.width,
                height: cachedValues.height
            }, function () {
                $parent.removeClass('open');
            });

            $parent.find('.closePost').addClass('closePostHide');
        }
    });

};
$(document).ready(profilePostsClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like following way by adding and removing class

**JQuery:**

```
$('.largeBox, .smallBox, .longBox').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('increaseSize');
        $('.closePost', this).removeClass('closePostHide');
    });

$('.glyphicon-remove').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
        $('.glyphicon-remove').parent().parent().removeClass('increaseSize');
        $('.closePost', this).addClass('closePostHide');
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
.increaseSize{
    width: 100%;
       height: 40%;
}
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/jvkhmpbt/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to use a toggle and do the animation in CSS3

```
$("img").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If we continue on Rover his answer, we can use the `switchClass` function in jQuery Ui. ([source](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/))

This function let's you switch the classes of an object, creating an animation in the difference between those classes.

Example code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/125e04hc/)

```
<div class="large"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.large{
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: red;
}

.small {
   width: 10%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color:green;
}
```

JS:

```
$("div").switchClass("large","small",500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add one more identical class to each of `smallBox`,`largeBox` and `longBox` which will be called `parentd` to identify `parent div` and animate it back and add below js:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jvkhmpbt/1/)**

```
$('.closePost').on('click',function(e)
{    
        $(this).closest('.parentd')
        .animate({
                     width: '40%',
                     height: 'auto'
        },200).removeAttr('style');
        $(this).addClass('closePostHide');
        e.stopPropagation();
});
```